# How to change one mat-cell value based on a another summarised mat-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'm developing in Angular & Angular Material, which I'm new to (on 8 atm), and usually manage to find answers to most of my problems, but can't find an answer for this problem.

I have a Master-detail mat-table of transactions, with the master mat-table having a 'total' sum of amount from the detail rows. What I'm now trying to do, and cannot find an answer, is to have another 'status' column display text depending on positive\negative 'total' value.

This is my Master-detail json.

```json
[
    {
        "id": "50891",
        "description": "February 2020",
        "detail": [
            {
                "Id": 88708,
                "PaymentDate": "2020-02-24",
                "Amount": -58.0,
                "Method": "Charge",
                "Type": "Charge"
            },
            {
                "Id": 88709,
                "PaymentDate": "2020-03-02",
                "Amount": -58.0,
                "Method": "Charge",
                "Type": "Charge"                
            }
        ]
    }   
]
```

This is my mat-cell columns. The 'total' column is calling a function to calculate the total 'amount' value.

```angular
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ ?? }} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="total">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Total </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ total(row) | currency: 'GBP' }} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

This is the function in the ts file doing the calculation.

```js
total(model: any) {
    return model.details.map(t => t.amount).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
}
```

So, what I'm looking to do now is set a 'debit' or 'credit' text value in the 'status' column based on the calculated 'total' column. I searched and searched and have been unable to find the answer or figure it out. Does anyone know a way in which I can do that?

Many thanks

Comment: i didn't get your wuestion can you create a live stackblitz example and share link here so developers can get  and help you in what you want to achive

Comment: Here is the stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-x98nar

I need the detail amounts summed on the month level but re-calculated on edit\delete so can't just do this on load in the json data.

And then based on the summed value I would like a credit\debit status and it is this that I require some help with. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same format you are using for the total by interpolating a function that returns "debit" or "credit" based on the total value.

```html
  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ getStatus(row) }} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

```js
getStatus(mode: any) {
  let total = model.details.map(t => t.amount).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  return (total < 0) 'debit' : 'credit';
}
```

Another strategy you might want to consider is to iterate through your data and add these properties (status & total) to the data on component initialization. When you place a function in a template as you are doing here, these functions get run every time there is a re-render, so running once for all at the beginning is less expensive.

Comment: I did think I could do the first solution but thought unproductive to do the calculation in 2 places. I do have a delete\edit option on transactions so would need to recalculate when something changes.

Comment: If you don't want to do the calculation more than once, then you definitely shouldn't put the function call in the template, as it gets called on every re-render. You can add that properties to the objects on init, and then iterate through again to re-calculate when you add & delete from the data set.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I'll take your suggestion on board and try that.

Comment: Got something working. I'm just updating the objects as per your suggestion. Thanks Dylan.